# VS2019 Extension how to add a new Top Menu

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to create a VS2019 extension that adds a entire new menu to the top menu. My goal for this is to write an extension that actually works with the TC3 XAE shell which is a VS isolated shell application. This has been done by one guy with the [STweep extension.](https://www.stweep.com/)

[Top Menu of STweep in the XAE shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izzn2.png)

Through some digging to install an extension into the XAE shell you just have to manually place the unzipped .vsix file contents into a folder.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Beckhoff\TcXaeShell\Common7\IDE\Extensions

This works with the demo of STweep. I can simply copy and paste the contents of his extension into the XAE shell and it works.

So I am trying to develop my own extension. I am trying to do this with VS2019 community. I can easily build an extension that adds a button to an existing menu like tools or edit. There are a bunch of videos on how to do this. This will work in VS2019 but no the XAE shell. If I take the same extension that works in VS2019 and puts a button in the Tolls menu, it doesn't work in the XAE shell. Not surprised. So, I am trying to figure out how to make a new top menu and this seems to be rather difficult to accomplish.

I found this guys [site](https://www.visualstudioextensibility.com/2016/10/18/samples-how-to-create-top-menus-sub-menus-context-menus-toolbars/). He has an example of how to make a top menu item. It must have been built in VS2015 as it doesn't work in VS2019 when compiled. I went down the path of migrating the project and even in VS2019 when running the project the top menu doesn't show up.

Does anyone have a good link to a tutorial on how to accomplish adding a top menu in VS2019?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone else has this problem, the solution was to start the extension in VS2017. It looks like the shell for XAE is built with the isolated shell 2105 or 2017. Starting an extension project with VS2017 worked right out of the box. Same steps in VS2019, different libraries are used and it simply doesn't work. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to Extensions - Customize Menu to enable top level menu for your extension:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response but that isn't it. In the XAE shell you don't have that option. In regular VS you do and Yes that does work in that instance. I have been trying to use the Visual Studio Community toolkit 2019 to build this extension. I think this is the issue. If I build an extension with the stock VSIX project it seems to show up but them my commands don't work.